# GitHub: Fork is always one commit behid afer pull accepted

Tags: git, github, version-control

There is a project on GitHub, where I frequently contribute, that has its own repo at `ORGANIZATION/PROJECT`.

I have forked that repo to my own `USERNAME/PROJECT`, and then cloned that repo to my PC to work on my contributions.

After I make a change to the code, I push it to `USERNAME/PROJECT` and when I have several changes ready, I do a `pull request` to send those changes to `ORGANIZATION/PROJECT`.

When that pull request is accepted, my repo at GitHub displays a message saying "This branch is 1 commit behind PROJECT:master.", and I can no longer push changes from my PC to my repo (I get `git rejected non-fast-forward...` messages).

I have to pull from origin so I can push new changes.

But now my repo has a commit with 0 files changed, and it is one commit ahead of `ORGANIZATION/PROJECT`.

And when I try to sync both repos again, I create a new 0-files commit and the other repo is one commit behind.

I think there has to be something wrong with my workflow, but I cannot understand what... any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to pull from origin so I can push new changes.

Git does not allow you to push code if you're not fully synched with the remote repo, this is why you have to pull the code from the remote repository.

> But now my repo has a commit with 0 files changed
>   Its called merge commit. If you wish to not to have it you will have to set your repo to support fast-forward commits.

Here is a short article explaining how to avoid such a commit.
http://kernowsoul.com/blog/2012/06/20/4-ways-to-avoid-merge-commits-in-git/

Can you please share a screenshot with the command you executing? or at least update the Questions with the command.

Comment: Thanks codeWizard, your link is spot on the problem. However, I think I do not fully understand the solution. My fork at GitHub still displays the "This branch is 1 commit behind 400plus:master." message, yet when I run "git pull --rebase" on my local repo, it answers with "Current branch master is up to date.".